# RefreshRate в DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC

Tags: c++, directx-11

На [mdsn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/dxgicommon/ns-dxgicommon-dxgi_rational?redirectedfrom=MSDN) есть информация о структуре DXGI_RATIONAL

> **Numerator** An unsigned integer value representing the top of the rational number.

> **Denominator** An unsigned integer value representing the bottom of the rational number.

Что дает эта структура? Как понять

*Целое число без знака, представляющее верхнюю часть рационального числа.*

и

*Целое число без знака, представляющее нижнюю часть рационального числа.*

Answer (score 1):

Рациональное число в математике — это дробь вида a/b. Так что ее числитель a и есть верхняя часть дроби, а знаменатель b — нижняя часть.

И это явно указано в именах полей структуры:

```
typedef struct DXGI_RATIONAL {
  UINT Numerator;
  UINT Denominator;
} DXGI_RATIONAL;
```

Ибо в английском Numerator и есть числитель, а Denominator — знаменатель.

Видимо, они дали такое описание в терминах "верх-низ" в расчете на тех, кто плохо учил математику в школе :)

Comment: Что это дробь - я понял, я имел ввиду *Что дает эта структура? Как понять?*

Для чего эта дробь? Сначала я подумал, что это ограничитель "FPS", но после того, как подставил значения `sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
 sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;` У меня никакого ограничения не сработало. Вот и возникает вопрос: для чего это?

Answer (score 1):

Эта структура задает [Рациональное число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE), проще говоря обыкновенную дробь вида `Numerator / Denominator`. В контексте задания частоты обновления в `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC` эта структура имеет следующий смысл: в числителе указывается частота тактового генератора, а в знаменателе - количество тактов на один кадр, получается частота обновления в Герцах. Например для NTSC video - 30000/1001 - 29.97 Гц. Для игровых приложений же более обычны значения 60/1 - 60 Гц. Значение задается посредством двух целых чисел, а не одним числом с плавающей точкой чтобы избегать погрешностей вычислений с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Что это дробь - я понял, я имел ввиду *Что дает эта структура? Как понять?*

Для чего эта дробь? Сначала я подумал, что это ограничитель "FPS", но после того, как подставил значения `sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
 sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;` У меня никакого ограничения не сработало. Вот и возникает вопрос: для чего это?

Comment: @Barev Это действительно ограничитель fps. Однако чтобы он использовался, первый параметр при вызовах Present должен быть больше 0. Еще при работе полноэкранной swap chan это величина задает физическую частоту обновления монитора.

Comment: А можно как-то переопределять значения во время исполнения программы? Например, я задал `->Present(1u, 0u);  Numerator = 0; Denominator = 0;` И в ходе исполнения программы хочу ограничить фпс `Numerator = 60; Denominator = 1;` Можно ли потвторно вызвать `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`? Если нет, тогда как этьо можно реализовать?

Comment: @Barev Можно. Более того, приложение обязательно должно быть готово пересоздать устройство и swap chain в случае получения DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED или DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET. Однако лучше создавать устройство и swap chain раздельно. Ведь пересоздание устройства - это значит и пересоздание всех ресурсов. И если хотите поменять только частоту обновления, то будет достаточно пересоздать только swap chain.

Comment: Есть ли какие-то ограничения при выставлении лока фпс? `Present(1u, 0u);` у меня, `Numerator = 60; Denominator = 1;`, но лок не срабатывает

Comment: @Barev Должен срабатывать.